# Rake aborted ! Issue installing Octopress

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundle

I m trying to install the Octopress on my windows. As per their Tutorial on their [website](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/). But when I type the command

```
rake install
```

It gives me the following error

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\octopress>rake install
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. U
sing bundle exec may solve this.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And as the error says I need to install rake 0.9.2
I tried it doing with the following command.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\octopress>gem install rack -v=0.9.2.0
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rack' (= 0.9.2.0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rack
```

I already have Ruby & Gems installed on my PC. But I m not able to figure out how to solve this issue. How do I even use the "bundle exec" to install Octopress ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to use the bundle exec in this way

```
bundle exec rake install
```

This might just solve you problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this with `bundle update`
it's a dependency problem and not big deal

Answer (score 0):

The first time you spelled it rake and the second time you spelled it rack

Answer (score 0):

First update the documentation to say,

```
bundle exec rake install
```

Then update the Gemfile.lock with,

```
bundle update
```